# How to get approximative word with fulltext catalog?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I created a full text catalog under SQL

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FTS_Catalog
WITH accent_sensitivity = OFF
```

Next, I created a unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_idXML 
ON dbo.customers_table(idXML)
```

And finally a full text index

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
ON [dbo].[CUSTOMERS_TABLE] (name)
KEY INDEX ui_idXML ON FTS_Catalog
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO
```

My purpose is get result and approximative result.

Example, if I'm looking for the word 'claver', I would like to get the word 'clavier', 'claved', etc... as result. I'm looking to have 80% of the word.

I've tried with contains and freetext, but I got only 'claver'.

I think I am misssing an option.

Here is the query I tested

```
SELECT name 
FROM CUSTOMERS_TABLE 
WHERE CONTAINS (name, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "claver")');

SELECT name 
FROM CUSTOMERS_TABLE 
WHERE CONTAINS (name, 'ISABOUT("claver" WEIGHT(1.0) )');

SELECT name 
FROM CUSTOMERS_TABLE 
WHERE FREETEXT (name, 'claver');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i found

```
SELECT name FROM CUSTOMERS_TABLE WHERE CONTAINS(name,'"clav*"');
```

So i decided to get 80% for the text. 
For this i'm doing like below and add wildcard at the end.

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(50) = 'clavier';

SELECT substring(@string, 0, (len(@string)*80)/100)+'*'
```